# React typescript: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components

It is a React component to create a Check Box Button, I am having this error in onCheckboxBtnClick(1),onCheckboxBtnClick(2)...

```
 const [cSelected, setCSelected] = useState([])
 const [rSelected, setRSelected] = useState<number>()

 const onCheckboxBtnClick = (selected: never) => {
  const index = cSelected.indexOf(selected)
  if (index < 0) {
   cSelected.push(selected)
  } else {
   cSelected.splice(index, 1)
  }
  setCSelected([...cSelected])
 }
 return (
  <div>
   <h5>Checkbox Buttons</h5>
   <ButtonGroup>
    <Button color="primary" onClick={() => onCheckboxBtnClick(1)} active={cSelected.includes(1)}>
     One
    </Button>
    <Button color="primary" onClick={() => onCheckboxBtnClick(2)} active={cSelected.includes(2)}>
     Two
    </Button>
    <Button color="primary" onClick={() => onCheckboxBtnClick(3)} active={cSelected.includes(3)}>
     Three
    </Button>
   </ButtonGroup>
   <p>Selected: {JSON.stringify(cSelected)}</p>
  </div>
 )
}

export default Example
```

and I get this error: `Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.`
How can I fix this?

Comment: please share reproducable example

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried copying this over into a Codesandbox and wasn't able to produce what you're describing.

What line do you get this error?

Codesandbox for further discussion: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-shadow-6ec4g?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Problem resolved, we should pass number array to usestate